# Why my sed command doesn't work sometimes with the r flag

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I am really confused.

Sometimes this flag works fine

`sed -e 's/dd//gp' file`

sometimes i need to use

`sed -re 's/dd//gp' file`

sometimes this

`sed -ren 's/dd//gp' file`

and sometimes

`sed -n 's/dd//gp' file`

Just now i was trying to suppress the outout but i was keeping coming with `-ren` flag

which worked for other regex last week

Now i had to use `-n` only to suppress the ouput

what is the difference between combinations

I have this commnad

`sed -n 's/\/\*\*//gp' file` which works witn `-n` but not with `-en`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `man sed` to determine what the various flags of `sed` are used for.

The `-e` flag is only necessary if specifying multiple quote blocks to `sed`.

```
echo "foo" | sed 's/foo/bar/'
=> bar
echo "foo" | sed -e 's/foo/bar/' -e 's/bar/baz/'
=> baz
```

The `-r` flag expands `sed`'s regular expressions to use extended regular expressions.

```
echo "foo" | sed 's/f??/bar/'
=> foo
echo "foo" | sed -r 's/f??/bar/'
=> baroo
```

The `-n` flag does not suppress output, instead it suppresses the automatic output of whatever is in the pattern space. If you use `p` or the `s///p` flag then printing will still happen explicitly and produce output.

For example:

```
echo "foo" | sed ''
=> foo
echo "foo" | sed -n ''
=> 
echo "foo" | sed -n 'p'
=> foo
echo "foo" | sed -n 's/foo/bar/p'
=> bar
```

If you'd like to suppress `sed`'s output you can redirect `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to `/dev/null` like this:

```
sed '<commands>' &>/dev/null
```

See [this](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUQzXLQ6jvHL-Kw9I5H6dvFHal-ynWSTA) video series for an introduction to `sed`.

Comment: how does the order of flags work. I find that `-rn` work but `-nr` dont

Comment: Can you provide an example? That shouldn't matter.

Comment: I tried this `sed -ner 's/ss//gp' menu.php
sed: can't read s/ss//gp: No such file or directory` and then i tried this `sed -rne 's/ss//gp' menu.php` and it worked

Comment: @Conner: nope. The `-e` flags expects an argument, so in `-ner`, the `r` is interpreted as a sed script, not as a `sed` option, and `sed` no longer looks for script in its argument list.

Comment: Yeah, what he said :-)

Comment: Except you can read from a script in the argument list with `-f`